# How do I use a variable in a UNC path in powershell?

Tags: powershell, variables, filepath

I'm trying to count the contents of a folder on a remote server.

I know that:

```
Get-ChildItem \\ServerName\c$\foldername -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum
```

works a treat.

However I'm trying to make the server name a variable, by user input, but I can't get the path to accept any variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
$server = Read-Host "Enter server name"
Get-ChildItem \\$server\users -recurse | measure-object length -sum
```

Comment: I wonder then if this is a powershell version problem, because I can't get that to work.

I get a:

"Cannot find path '\\servername\C$\foldername' because it does not exist." error

Comment: Well I've downloaded v 2.0 and I still can't get that to work.

It looks like it -should- work. I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Dunno.  It works for me on V2 `gci \\$servername\c$\users`.  BTW if servername is a variable it must be `\\$servername\c$`.

Comment: Ended up using:
$server = Read-Host "Enter server name"
$share = Read-Host "Enter share name"
Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$share" -recurse | measure-object length -sum

Thanks Keith

Comment: I just verified this works for me in V1 of PowerShell. I also experimented with various double and single quotes and found that it behaves best without quoting at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this in the shell and you want a one-liner, try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$(Read-Host)\share" -recurse | Measure-Object length -sum
```

This won't produce a message asking for input, but saves assigning to a variable that you may not need, and if you are running this from the shell then you know the input that is needed anyway!

Also double quotes will mean a variable is evaluated so:

```
$hello = "Hello World"
Write-Host "$hello"
Hello world
```

Or as Keith Hill has pointed out:

```
$hello = "Hello World"
Write-Host $hello
Hello World
```

Where as single quotes won't evaluate the variable so:

```
$hello = "Hello World"
Write-Host '$hello'
$hello
```

So if you are using variables and you have spaces in the path use " ".

Comment: In your Write-Host example no quotes are needed at all.  Even in the context of command mode parsing, you don't need double quotes around a variable.  Try this on V2 - `gci $pshome\modules` - look ma - no quotes.  :-)

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the comment, that is true, but the reason I put them to demonstrate the difference in behaviour between double and single quotes. I have amended the example to demo this out though. Thanks for pointing that out. :-)